# rtools40 Windows installation issue with TAR packages

Tags: r, tar, rtools

I recently installed Rtools package for downloading and unpacking TAR packages. I was using the following code from an old package 'TCGA2STAT' using 'getTCGA()' function.

```
brca = getTCGA(disease = "BRCA", data.type = 'RNASeq2', clinical = TRUE, type = 'RPKM')
```

to which I was getting an error

> Error: TAR is not installed in the system. Data unzip failed.

There was a similar question from 2018 where someone answered to do the following

```
Sys.setenv(TAR ="C:\\Program Files\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\tar")
Sys.setenv(R_GZIPCMD ="C:\\Program Files\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\gzip")
```

On checking whether it worked or not I entered

```
Sys.which('tar')
```

and response

> tar
> "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\tar.exe"

while `Sys.getenv('tar')` was showing

> [1] "C:\Program Files\rtools40\usr\bin\tar.exe"

Please help in resolving this.

Comment: R does not see the installation of Rtools, try setting `Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0("c:/Program Files/rtools40/usr/bin;", Sys.getenv("PATH")))` and then checking again `Sys.which("tar")`.

Comment: `Sys.which('tar')` still returned the same System32 directory tar.exe file.